# ceph-deploy for CentOS 7 does not find ceph-02:/dev/sdb file

Tags: ceph

I am trying to activate ceph osd by following command:

```
ceph-deploy osd prepare ceph-02:/dev/sdb
```

And found following error

```
[ceph-02][WARNIN] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/sdb'

[ceph-02][ERROR ] RuntimeError: command returned non-zero exit status: 1

[ceph_deploy.osd][ERROR ] Failed to execute command: /usr/sbin/ceph-disk -v 
prepare --cluster ceph --fs-type xfs -- /dev/sdb

[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] GenericError: Failed to create 1 OSDs
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1 :

parted -s /dev/sdb mklabel gpt mkpart primary xfs 0% 100%

step 2:

reboot

step3:

mkfs.xfs /dev/vdb -f

ceph-deploy osd create --data /dev/sdb server-hostname

its worked i tested this command.